# how to set the pytest.param id automatically?

Tags: python, parameters, pytest

I have a parametrized test:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', [
    [1,2,3],
    ['a'],
    [[],[1],['a']],
])
def test_bla(args):
    assert all(args)
```

When running it, I get the following output:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.6.12, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/bla/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.6.12', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.15.0-132-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial', 'Packages': {'pytest': '6.0.2', 'py': '1.9.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'metadata': '1.10.0'}}
rootdir: ...
plugins: metadata-1.10.0
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                              

my_test.py::test_bla[args0] PASSED
my_test.py::test_bla[args1] PASSED
my_test.py::test_bla[args2] FAILED    <---------- Note that this is not very descriptive :(

=================================================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_bla[args2] ________________________________________________________________________________________________

args = [[], [1], ['a']]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('args', [
        [1,2,3],
        ['a'],
        [[],[1],['a']],
    ])
    def test_bla(args):
>       assert all(args)
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = all([[], [1], ['a']])

my_test.py:8: AssertionError
=========================================================================================== short test summary info ============================================================================================
FAILED my_test.py::test_bla[args2] - AssertionError: assert False
========================================================================================= 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.11s ==========================================================================================
```

What I want, is to get in the output the actual args used, e.g.:

```
my_test.py::test_bla[args0] PASSED
my_test.py::test_bla[args1] PASSED
my_test.py::test_bla[[], [1], ["a"]] FAILED    <---------- Note the change here
```

This I got by editing the `parameterization`:

```
pytest.param([[],[1],['a']], id='[], [1], ["a"]'),
```

Is there a way for pytest to just take the parameter and make it's `id = str(param)`? (basically automating what I just edited myself in the test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an [ID function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids) to the `ids` parameter of the @pytest.mark.parametrize decorator:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('args', [
    [1,2,3],
    ['a'],
    [[],[1],['a']],
], ids=str)
def test_bla(args):
    assert all(args)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Didn't find it in the docs, did I miss it?

Comment: It's the last code example in the section I linked to.

Comment: `ids=lambda args: str(args)` can be just `ids=str` ;-)

Comment: @JackTaylor do you mean the `ids=idfn`? section?

Comment: @CIsForCookies That's the one. There's a description as well. I quote: "In test_timedistance_v2, we specified ids as a function that can generate a string representation to make part of the test ID. So our datetime values use the label generated by idfn, but because we didn’t generate a label for timedelta objects, they are still using the default pytest representation."

Comment: @JackTaylor I saw it while I scanned the docs - and hoped for a better and more concise way - such as yours (and better - such as @hoefling)